# Oracle SQL possible to trim characters before a character is found?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, trim

Not sure if it is possible to do with trim in a select statement:

Basically want to trim anything characters in a string BEFORE a character is found:

say there are values (names) Oliver, Dave and I want to trim all characters before 'v' is found so those values would be 'ver' and 've' afterwards

Again it kind of sounds too complicated for a trim statement unless there is an easy way to combine it with a LIKE to search for such a thing.

May be getting ahead of myself here but would be a useful thing if anyone can help enlighten it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('David', 'v.*') from dual
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('David', 'v.*')
```

Description about REGEXP_SUBSTR: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm

REGEXP_LIKE: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

Comment: Seems to have worked, can you explain how regexp works compared to regular substr?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with REGEXP, or with SUBSTR/INSTR:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(mycolumn,'v') > 0
            THEN SUBSTR(mycolumn,INSTR(mycolumn,'v'))
            ELSE mycolumn
       END
FROM ....
```